# Using the data from a collect feedback sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-list, sharepointdocumentlibrary

**I've got a SharePoint library of documents I want to collect feedback on.**

So far I've achieved this using the built-in collect feedback workflow. The information collected from the reviewers goes into the workflow history for the specific document.

Is there anyway I can access this information using SharePoint designer and perhaps populate a list filled with the reviewers comments?

I've been searching google for ways to do this and there doesn't seem to be any concise instructions about how I might go about it.

As this is a small project, I've been avoiding using Visual Studio for custom workflows, hence I'm looking for ways to achieve this using SharePoint designer.

Any advice much appreciated, Thanks.